# My CSS and JS isn't being into the webpage

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I'm having some problem with loading CSS and JS to my page. I am using PHP and Xampp for my project.

The files are like this.

```
My Site
   - CSS
      - index.css
   - JS
      - index.js
   - Index.php
```

(Sorry, I don't know to make that folder tree)

In the PHP file I did this -

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
And I guess you know abut the JS as well.
```

But the CSS won't load. But if I keep the CSS outside the CSS folder it works. But that makes the whole Folder unorganized and haed to find files. Can anyone please help me with it ?

Comment: Did you try `href="CSS/index.css`? Note `CSS` is all capital letters

Comment: How do you know it doesn't load? What do the debugging tools in your browser say about the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Paths are **case sensitive**.

If your folder is `CSS` you should reference it like so:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/index.css">
```

Same with the JS.

### Update:

As [Quentin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19068/quentin) pointed out in the comment, it may not be your case since you're most probably using **Windows**. But if you somehow enabled the case sensitivity in your folder (for example using `fsutil`) it can still affect you.

If you're using **linux**, then my answer still applies.

Comment: "Paths are case sensitive" — They can be, but the OP said they were using XAMPP which is most commonly used on Windows, which doesn't typically use case-sensitive file systems, so path resolution for static files is case *insensitive*.

Comment: Yeah, true, somehow missed information about XAMPP. But afaik, NTFS is a case sensitive system, the Windows API only locks the functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Is browser caching tripping you up? Maybe it grabbed a blank version of css/index.css at some point and doesn't want to update it.

Chrome and Firefox (and probably others) automatically disable caching while the developer window is open.
Press F12 to open the developer window and refresh your page.